# Using different random values at each recursion step

Tags: random, recursion

I have the following code:

```
ϕ[0] := π/4
ϕ[n_] := Exp[-n] ϕ[n - 1] + Sqrt[1 - Exp[-2 n]] M
M = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
```

For this recursion relation, is the normal deviate taking a random variable during each recursion or is it just taking one for the whole recursion process?

Thanks,

Comment: M is a nailed thing in your code ...

Comment: As it is one for the whole recursion. You can use `M:=...` if you need a new one at each recursion.

Comment: Thanks guys! Always helpful, I'll push you both up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Set (=)` stores the value at the time of computation, while `SetDelayed (:=)` stores the definition, so that the value is computed again each time it is called. Therefore, writing

```
M = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
```

means using the same value over and over, while writing

```
M := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]
```

means computing a new `RandomVariate` at each iteration.

---

Moreover, no matter what your choice is about `M`, while we're at it, you might want to do [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) for the whole process, i.e. [write](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)

```
ϕ[0] = π/4
ϕ[n_] := ϕ[n] = Exp[-n] ϕ[n - 1] + Sqrt[1 - Exp[-2 n]] M
```

This way when computing `ϕ[n]` you store the value in your memory, so that when computing `ϕ[n + 1]` you only have to recall it, instead of computing it from scratch. It is usually worth it to trade memory for speed this way.